# How to get the folder names in UTF-8 using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I have a database that is in Spanish language.

When I query the database i use Spanish accent words. these words come from many folder names that I have on my hard drive. e.g i have a folder called 'Canadá' and I query the db saying `select from table where country='$name'`. 
In my code im doing `$name=GetFolderName()` which reads whatever the folder name is.

This does not work. If I hardcode the folder name like `$name="Canadá"`, then the query executes fine, but if i read the folder name via PHP, the query does not execute successfully. Maybe it is caused because my db table is set in UTF-8.

Is there a way to read the folder name such that the name I read is converted in UTF-8 format?

Comment: On what platform are you doing this? NTFS uses UTF-16 (I believe) for filenames? If you're on Linux/Unix, what's your shell's locale set to? You may not be loading utf-8 filenames.

Comment: Try [mb_detect_encoding()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) on the string and see what it says.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you are quoting right. If `GetFolderName()` doesn't return `"Canadá"` your Query will most likely fail. Always check the actual Query String if you're having Trouble with SQL Queries.

Comment: i echo'd the result of getFolderName and it is Canadá . but somehow this is nt in utf8...as i said if i hardcode it...the query executes fine

Comment: If you just return the Value of the Folder name the actual Query will look like `SELECT ... WHERE name=Canadá`. Since name is a String it should look like `SELECT ... WHERE name="Canadá"`

Answer (score 0):

First, correct the quoting in your query:

```
$query = "select from table where country='$name'";
```

Next, try printing variable `$name` before sending it to the database as part of the SQL - to see what it's actually set to.

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for an answer to this question, but I stumbled on the answer myself, just last night.  Here's what I learned:

Someone elsewhere suggested the use of `basename(__DIR__).PHP_EOL;` I could not understand why this didn't work until I echoed the name twice.  There was a space ad the end of the filename.  the `.PHP_EOL` adds the space, which affects your DB query.  So my solution is:

```
$folder = basename(__DIR__);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE folderid = '".$folder."'";
```

This worked perfectly for me.  I use it to allow for a web page to have links specific to the person, content, or organization within a business directory, using a folder specific to that end.

I realize this question is years old, but I hope this helps someone.